# How to make this box to a triangle in css

Tags: html, css

please check out this code pen link

want to make the square beside home to triangle upside down. when i hover - its working correctly

https://codepen.io/shaswat/pen/gXLBwo

please help me to make that square to triangle .creating a navigation bar

after I hover its working correctly by transforming to upside

```css
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: black;
  padding-bottom: 3px; 
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #0d0d0d;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: red;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a.active {
  background: grey;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #d64e34;
  background: grey;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active {
  background: green;
}
#cssmenu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
  content:""; 
  position: absolute; 
  height: 0; 
  width: 0; 
  border: 8px solid orange; 
  top: 40%;
  right: 5px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 8px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom-color: orange; 
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class='active' href='#'>Products</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line 119 replace orange with transparent. And add border-top-color: orange;. If you make border-bottom-color instead of border-top-color arrow will be reversed.

```
border: 8px solid transparent;
border-top-color: orange;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the code of `#cssmenu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before` like this :

```
#cssmenu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: orange;
  top: 40%;
  right: 5px;
}
```

the  full code :

```css
/* Menu CSS */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu>ul {
  background: black;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:before,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu>ul {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu>ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #0d0d0d;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  background: red;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li>a.active {
  background: grey;
}


/* Childs */

#cssmenu>ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#cssmenu>ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background: transparent;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #d64e34;
  background: grey;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li a:active {
  background: green;
}

#cssmenu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: orange;
  top: 40%;
  right: 5px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: orange;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class='active' href='#'>Products</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `#cssmenu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before` have `border: 8px solid orange;` replace it with `border: 8px solid transparent;` and `border-top-color: orange;`. This will give you a down arrow and when you hover it will turn into an up arrow.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use a font. Replace the last two rules with this:

```
#cssmenu>ul>li>a::after {
  content: "⏷";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: .5;
  font-size: 24px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0);
  margin-left: 5px;
  color:orange;
  transition:.5s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a::after {
  transform:rotate(180deg) translate(5px,-5px);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition:.5s ease;
}
```

### Demo

```css
/* Menu CSS */

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu>ul {
  background: black;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:before,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu>ul {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu>ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #0d0d0d;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  background: red;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li>a.active {
  background: grey;
}


/* Childs */

#cssmenu>ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#cssmenu>ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background: transparent;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid #d64e34;
  background: grey;
}

#cssmenu>ul ul li a:active {
  background: green;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-of-type>a::after {
  content: "⏷";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: .5;
  font-size: 24px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-5px,0);
  margin-left: 5px;
  color:orange;
  transition:.5s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:first-of-type:hover>a::after {
  transform:rotate(180deg) translate(5px,-5px);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition:.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Product 3</a></li>
      </ul>


    </li>
    <li><a class='active' href='#'>Products</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use only one font and apply rotation of hover `#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg) scaleX(1.3);
}` :)

Comment: I was thinking of that and add a transition to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

just change this styles

```
#cssmenu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
    content:""; 
    position: absolute; 
    height:0; 
    width: 0; 
    border-top: 8px solid orange; 
    border-left: 8px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 8px solid transparent; 
    top: 40% ;
    right:5px;
 }
```